# Adding left barbutton on navigation controller

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am trying to add the left bar button in navigation controller but it is not working. My code:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(204,165,99,255);
        this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromFile("hamburger_menu")
            , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
            , (sender, args) => {
                // button was clicked
            })
        , true);

        this.Title = "Dashboard";
```

I used code from [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/add_a_nav_bar_right_button/) url. hamburger_menu is an image present in my Assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading image with UIImage.FromFile but when I changed it to UIImage.FromBundle, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the left bar button to a particular UIViewController. We shouldn't set its NavigationController's NavigationItem.

Be aware of that every UIViewController has a NavigationItem property. Set its own NavigationItem to achieve your effect:

```
this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(
    new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("hamburger_menu")
    , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
    , (sender, args) => {
    // button was clicked
})
, true);
```

Moreover because UINavigationController is a subClass of UIViewController, you can set its NavigationItem. But this item is not what you want.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code with image name both "hamburger_menu" & "hamburger_menu.png" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried to hide back button with this.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true; But it is also not working.

Comment: I am using MVVMCross here, I hope it is not impacting my navigation controller.

Comment: @pankaj Did you try this in Xamarin.iOS or Froms? You can try `this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem();` Moreover, where did you put this code?

Comment: I am working in Xamarin.iOS, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I had to change UIImage.FromFile to UIImage.FromBundle and it worked. thanks for the help.

Comment: @pankaj It may be not the problem of the initialization of barButtonItem. I find you construct your UIImage with FromFile. Does this image exist in your project? Then try FromBundle(). You can change the image with Title to test which problem it is.

Comment: @pankaj these two methods can both initialize an effective UIImage. It depends on the position you put your image source on.